# ASP.Net MVC:How to rewrite url by middleware in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, httpmodule

In asp.net 4.0 we can use work with the http module to rewrite module like so:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CountryCodeInUrl = "", redirectUrl="";
    var countryCode = CookieSettings.ReadCookie();
    if (countryCode=="")
    {
        countryCode = "gb";
    }

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Length >= 2)
    {
        CountryCodeInUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Substring(1, 2);
    }

    if (countryCode != CountryCodeInUrl)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Length >= 2)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Substring(1, 2) != "")
            {
                countryCode = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Substring(1, 2);
            }
        }
        if(!System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Contains(countryCode))
        {
            redirectUrl = string.Format("/{0}{1}", countryCode, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            redirectUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
        }
        CookieSettings.SaveCookie(countryCode);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectPermanent(redirectUrl);
    }   
}
```

How could I rewrite the code above using middleware in ASP.NET Core?

I have just partially read this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You pretty much just need to move the code to a middleware class, and use the Core HttpContext instead of the System.Web one.

A class like that would look like this:

//RedirectMiddleware.cs

```
public class RedirectMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RedirectMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        string CountryCodeInUrl = "", redirectUrl = "";
        var countryCode = CookieSettings.ReadCookie();
        if (countryCode == "")
        {
            countryCode = "gb";
        }

        if (context.Request.Path.Value.Length >= 2)
        {
            CountryCodeInUrl = context.Request.Path.Value.Substring(1, 2);
        }

        if (countryCode != CountryCodeInUrl)
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.Value.Length >= 2)
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.Value.Substring(1, 2) != "")
                {
                    countryCode = context.Request.Path.Value.Substring(1, 2);
                }
            }
            if (!context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(countryCode))
            {
                redirectUrl = string.Format("/{0}{1}", countryCode, context.Request.Path.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                redirectUrl = context.Request.Path.Value;
            }
            CookieSettings.SaveCookie(countryCode);
            context.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl, true);
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

To use it you then register it in you Startup.cs file, before you register the MVC middleware, like this:

```
app.UseMiddleware<RedirectMiddleware>();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I hope this'll get you started, you can see [this](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/writing-custom-middleware-in-asp-net-core-1-0/) blog post for more information on middleware.

Comment: it dose not redirect the page should get redirected but its not moving

Comment: You shouldn't need to redirect - you can literally change the request path as the request fires. Also if you use a Redirect it should terminate the pipeline and not invoke the next middleware (ie. no call `_next.Invoke()`)

Comment: Hii @Tobias, I am following your answer. I appended the query string to the redirect URL but not getting the query string parameters in the request URL in `Startup.cs` file.

Answer (score 8):

As long as you insert the rewrite middleware before other middleware that fires you can re-write the `Context.Request.Path` in the middleware code.

The Path is writable and any subsequent code/middleware will use the new path to process the request.

Using self-contained (app.Use()) middleware you can do:

```cs
app.Use(async (context,next) =>
{
    var url = context.Request.Path.Value;

    // Rewrite privacy URL to index
    if (url.Contains("/home/privacy"))
    {
        // rewrite to index
        context.Request.Path = "/home/index";
    }

    await next();
});
```

Unlike the `Repsonse.Redirect()` (which fires a new server request) the URL of the original request is not changed by this operation.

More info in this blog post:

[Back to Basics: URL Rewriting in ASP.NET Core](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Mar/13/Back-to-Basics-Rewriting-a-URL-in-ASPNET-Core)

Comment: Tried this in .NET 6. Appears to no longer work. You can set the `context.Request.Path` as indicated and it won't throw an error but it will also not change the path as desired.

Comment: yeap, it doesn't work in asp.net core 5

Comment: This does still work in .Net 6. One thing not explicitly mentioned in Rick's post which he does an excellent job explaining in the link - it is critical that the rewrite code block or middleware call appears before `app.UseRouting();` is called. [Here's that section in his block post.](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Mar/13/Back-to-Basics-Rewriting-a-URL-in-ASPNET-Core#routing-order-is-important)